# dc machine with brushes covering more than one commutator segment

Tags: current, dc-motor

i'm a bit confused with the current that flows in a wave armature winding of a dc machine. In a wave winding, there are two current paths, right? what happens when the brush covers more than one commutator segment, let say two and a half segment.
will the current be divided between the segments?

for example, if the total current is 250A, will the armature current be 125A or 125/2.5?

Comment: A brush will contact more than one commutator as an armature turns, else there would be dead spots. As another commutator comes in contact with the brush, voltage is applied but current starts out low. While the receding commutator, (having been connected longer), is conducting most of the current (that's where the arcing takes place). It is the total current that is important. I hope this helps.

Comment: @Optionparty, thanks for your reply. I am investigating the current density in the armature conductor, I need to know how much current is flowing in each conductor. The brush size is such that, at all time, the brush is in contact with two and a half segment. I'm wondering if the current splits into these 2.5 segments or not.

Comment: If the brush is 2.5 times a commutator contact width, and with the armature stalled, the current should be divided by a minimum of 3 and sometimes 4, depending on commutator angle.

Comment: A fairly good PDF that may help. http://www.uobabylon.edu.iq/uobColeges/ad_downloads/4_17925_628.pdf